# Count number of files in subdirectory in tgz file in linux

Tags: linux, count, tar, subdirectory

I have a tgz file with multiple subdirectories. How do I count the number of files in each subdirectory without untarring the file? I am using Linux CentOS on Amazon EC2.

For example, I have a tgz file with directory `dialogues/[0-9]` from http://dataset.cs.mcgill.ca/ubuntu-corpus-1.0/. Specifically, I'm looking at this tgz file: http://dataset.cs.mcgill.ca/ubuntu-corpus-1.0/ubuntu_dialogs.tgz

This tgz file has `dialogues` as the primary directory and then many subdirectories ranging from 1 - 999(?). I want to be able to count the number of files in all the subdirectories. For example, `dialogues/3` has 346,108 tsv files. `dialogues/4` has 269,023 tsv files. I want to be able to see the number of files in all the subdirectories. Is there a linux command to do this without untarring the file?

I want the output to be the name of subdirectories and then the number of files the subdirectory contains next to the name of the subdirectory. Something like:

`dialogs/3 - 346108`
`dialogs/4 - 269023`
`dialogs/5 - ######`

Etc. It doesn't have to be exact but that's the idea.

Comment: and what kind of output are you expecting? You may post the approximate sample output

Answer (score 1):

You can try this command:

`tar tzf ubuntu_dialogs.tgz | grep dialogs | grep tsv | xargs -i dirname {} | uniq -c`

I didn't download your 550 MB file, instead I tried this to count the jar files in a certain subdirectory inside one of my archives:

`tar tzf NetLogo-6.0.1-64.tgz | grep app/extensions | grep jar | xargs -i dirname {} | uniq -c`

and I get

```
  2 NetLogo 6.0.1/app/extensions/arduino
  1 NetLogo 6.0.1/app/extensions/array
  1 NetLogo 6.0.1/app/extensions/bitmap
  1 NetLogo 6.0.1/app/extensions/cf
  2 NetLogo 6.0.1/app/extensions/csv
  8 NetLogo 6.0.1/app/extensions/gis
  4 NetLogo 6.0.1/app/extensions/gogo
  6 NetLogo 6.0.1/app/extensions/ls
  2 NetLogo 6.0.1/app/extensions/matrix
 12 NetLogo 6.0.1/app/extensions/nw
  1 NetLogo 6.0.1/app/extensions/palette
  1 NetLogo 6.0.1/app/extensions/profiler
  2 NetLogo 6.0.1/app/extensions/r
  1 NetLogo 6.0.1/app/extensions/rnd
  1 NetLogo 6.0.1/app/extensions/sample
  1 NetLogo 6.0.1/app/extensions/sample-scala
  1 NetLogo 6.0.1/app/extensions/sound
  1 NetLogo 6.0.1/app/extensions/table
  6 NetLogo 6.0.1/app/extensions/vid
  3 NetLogo 6.0.1/app/extensions/view2.5d
```

(count of jars is in first column)

Answer (score 0):

```
tar tf ex.tgz | sed -n 's!/[^/]\+$!!p' | sort | uniq -c
```

Test:

```
mkdir -p a/c
touch a/{1,2,3,4,5,6}
touch a/c/{1,2}
mkdir b
touch b/{1,2,3}
tar cvfz ex.tgz a b
```

The output is then:

```
6 a
2 a/c
3 b
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but this does not give me all the counts for all the subdirectories. It only gives me the counts for some of the subdirectories. But knb's solution works, so I am okay. Still, thank you!